# Eclipse deadlocks when using pessimistic lock

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, apache-tomee

First thread uses:

```
    Master master = entityManager.find(Master.class, "MASTER", LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

From my understanding if another thread tries to execute the same statement it will hang until timed out and then throw PessimisticLockingException or similar.

However my other thread seems to be trying forever. I don't understand why. During boot I clearly see this:

```
[EL Finest]: 2014-09-03 14:05:51.441--ServerSession(800990938)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.lock.timeout; value=1
```

So it seems it should have been configure to timeout pretty quickly yet it never times out. However when the first thread commits it instantly continues so it's behaving just like the timeout was set to forever...

This is the log from the query that hangs:

```
[EL Finest]: 2014-09-03 14:05:52.124--UnitOfWork(189021365)--Thread(Thread[@Asynchronous classpath.ear - 1,5,main])--track pessimistic locked object com.kildeen.ref.domain.Master@42243b6 with UnitOfWork 189 021 365
//TABLE LOCKED BY FIRST THREAD
// lETS DO IT AGAIN IN ANOTHER THREAD
[EL Finer]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.101--ServerSession(800990938)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client acquired: 1749988512
[EL Finer]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.102--UnitOfWork(430231018)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
[EL Finer]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.102--ClientSession(1749988512)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 430231018
[EL Finest]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.102--UnitOfWork(430231018)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="readObject" referenceClass=Master sql="SELECT ID, TESTPROPERTY FROM mp_master WHERE (ID = ?)")
[EL Finer]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.102--ClientSession(1749988512)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
[EL Finest]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.102--ServerSession(800990938)--Connection(1844179384)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.102--ClientSession(1749988512)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: 2014-09-03 14:05:55.102--ClientSession(1749988512)--Connection(1575043618)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, TESTPROPERTY FROM mp_master WHERE (ID = ?) FOR UPDATE
    bind => [MASTER]
```

After that It is deadlocked...

Using TomEE 1.7 with Eclipselink 2.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to openjpa and it had much better logging:

```
<openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The database dictionary in use ("class org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary") reports that it does not have feature "SupportsSelectForUpdate".  This feature is needed to complete the current operation.  To force OpenJPA to try to use the feature anyway, set the following property:
openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary: SupportsSelectForUpdate=<value>
```

Turns out it worked with postgres